# Space in a Windows batch script (xcopy)

Tags: windows, datetime, batch-file

In a Windows (Windows 10) batch script I want to use xcopy with today's date.

```
SET DateToday=%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2% 
mkdir C:\Log_%DateToday% 
xcopy /y "Y:\GFPz %DateToday%" C:\Log_%DateToday%
```

The console comes out " File not found - * . * "

I want to copy this files every day:

[image]

Comment: You have a trailing blank at the end of the `SET` command.  Use this syntax as a best practice for using the `SET` command: `SET "DateToday=%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%"`

Comment: ...and if you are going to use a locale dependent method, I'd suggest this would be a slight improvement: `Set "DateToday=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're not grabbing the right parts of the date.

My date looks like: Thu 07/12/2018

Thus your SET would look like

SET DateToday=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%

Comment: The date variable is region dependent.  People in different countries have the parts of the date in different orders.

Comment: SET DateToday=%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%  = 20180712 for me  when i test echo %DateToday%